# How to pass type as a parameter to Generic return object

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method Handle which needs to return a generic type  GetCmdResult. Now, the type is a parameter being sent. But if I write "return new GetCmdResult" or "new PSDto()", it throws a compile time error. How can we pass the Type to the generics?

```
public class GetCmdResult<T> : CR
{
    public PSDto<T> PS{ get; set; }
}

public CR Handle(Type type)
{
    return new GetCmdResult<type>
               {
                   PS= new PSDto<type>()
               };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Can use a generic parameter on this method.

```
public CR Handle<T>(    
{
     return new GetCmdResult<T>
                   {
                       PS= new PSDto<T>()
                   };
}
```